# How to Build a Android App(.apk) file in Visual Studio WPF C# application?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019

I have built a WPF application in C# in Visual Studio 2019 for windows, but now I want to create a APK.
Can Anyone help?

Comment: Do you want to take a guess what "W" in the acronym "WPF" stands for?

Answer (score 0):

WPF or Windows Presentation Foundation, is, as the name implies, a technology for running applications on Windows.

APK is a file format for installing applications on Android mobile devices.

You cannot directly install or run a WPF application on an Android phone.   You can use a set of libraries called Xamarin, which is in some ways, similar to WPF (it can use the MVVM paradigm, for example), but your application will need quite a lot of rewriting to use that framework.